# background image not showing on my page

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have the image in the correct folder but I want to add a text box on top of an image and I was told the best way to do it is make the image a background image, but when I followed a tutorial it never appeared?
anyway here is my html

```
<div class="module">
                    <h2>blah blah</h2>
                            </div>
```

and my CSS

```
    .module {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 1530px;
  height: 717px;
  display:block;
  background: url('C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\champions\images\shop.png');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font: 14px PTSans;
}
```

the image is full width of the screen so I am using container-fluid in bootstrap and the text box will be in the middle of the image.

Comment: Are you using a local server or an external hosting?

Comment: local server in the office

Comment: A fiddle might work for us to help you. Try using background-image instead of background.

Comment: I am just getting the text 'blah blah' in a box on some white space which would be the size of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call the local file as background like this:

```
background: url("file://PATH-TO/file.jpg");
```

Keep in mind that the string inside parentheses should provide a [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to the file.

Also, you have the option to put a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) in it.

```
background: url("PATH-TO/file.jpg");
```

Comment: @Chimini If this worked, why did you unchecked its answer checkmark?!

Answer (score 1):

Change the backlashes. From this...

```
background: url('C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\champions\images\shop.png');
```

To this

```
 background: url('C:/Users/Jason/Desktop/champions/images/shop.png');
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine of your css. Try to use firefox or chrome debugger to check if the background image can be loaded or not. Try to change the value of the background-size. Sometimes the background image is too large that you can only see part of it (which may be completely white) on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong
try this: `url('images/shop.png')`   - if your css is in champions